# Can an m-way B-Tree have m odd?

Tags: algorithm, b-tree, clrs

I read on book **CLRS** that we have m-way B-tree where m is even. But is there is B-Tree where m is odd, if there is then how can we make changes in the code given in this book.

Comment: What would be a problem of an even _m_? What changes have you tried, is there a problem you have run into? (Would anyone believe in 2-3-trees _and_ [2-4-trees](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/ayg/CS251/slides/chap13a.pdf)?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By an m-way B-tree I assume you mean a B-tree where each internal node is allowed to have at most m children. According to CLRS's definition of a B-tree:

> Nodes have lower and upper bounds on the number of keys they can contain. We express these bounds in terms of a fixed integer t ≥ 2 called the minimum degree of the B-tree: ... an internal node may have **at most 2t children**.

So the maximum number of children will always be *even* – by this definition it can not be odd.

---

However, this is not the only definition of B-tree. There are many definitions with slight differences that ultimately, make little difference to the overall performance. This can cause confusion. There are some B-tree definitions that allow for odd upper bounds and those which don't. **CLRS's definition *does not* odd upper bounds** for the children count of internal nodes.

However, another formal definition of a B-tree is by [Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) [1998] (The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 3 (Second ed.), Addison-Wesley, ISBN 0-201-89685-0). **Knuth's definition *does* allow odd upper bounds**. While CLRS enumerates all min-max tree bounds of the form (t, 2t) for t ≥ 2, Knuth enumerates all tree bounds of the form (ceil(k/2), k) for k ≥ 2.

```
Knuth Order, k |  (min,max)  | CLRS Degree, t
---------------|-------------|---------------
     0         |      -      |        –
     1         |      –      |        –
     2         |      –      |        –
     3         |    (2,3)    |        –
     4         |    (2,4)    |      t = 2
     5         |    (3,5)    |        –
     6         |    (3,6)    |      t = 3
     7         |    (4,7)    |        –
     8         |    (4,8)    |      t = 4
     9         |    (5,9)    |        –
     10        |    (5,10)   |      t = 5
```

So for example, a [2-3 tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%E2%80%933_tree), (2,3), is a B-tree with Knuth order 3. But it is not a valid CLRS tree because it has an odd upper bound.

---

Changing code will not be easy as B-trees have a lot of code depending on variable t. One of the biggest changes would be inside: **B-TREE-SPLIT-CHILD(x,i)**, you'd need find a way to split a child with an odd number of children (an even number of keys) into nodes `y` and `z`. One of these two resulting nodes will have one more key than the other. If you're looking for code, I'd recommend looking on the Internet for an implementation of a B-tree that uses a definition similar to Knuth's (e.g. search for "Knuth Order B-tree").